# Java Web Framework for Ajax-based UI

Tags: java, ajax, frameworks

### Background

Looking to leverage an existing web framework to create a simple data-driven user interface.

### Problem

The mock-up allows creating JasperReports Server domains. Creation of domains is based on a data dictionary comprised of Business Areas and Column Clusters. It works as follows:

1. User selects one or more Business Areas.
   This causes the Column Cluster list to update (AJAX-style) with the available Column Clusters for the selected business areas.
2. User selects one or more Column Clusters.
3. User shuttles Column Clusters into Domain Content list.

The user has two options: **Create Domain** and **Upload Domain**.

Both buttons do the same thing: create an XML document based on the Domain Content list.

### Technologies

Here are the technologies I am considering:

- Servlet. Means hand-crafting database queries and jQuery code.
- Grails. There is no writing to the database, though.
- JavaServer Faces. Quite bulky, but it has shuttles.
- Facelets. Integrates with RichFaces.
- Eclipse + JBoss + RichFaces. ???
- Tapestry. ???

### Requirements

The fixed requirements:

- Apache Tomcat 6
- Java
- PostgreSQL (JDBC)
- Firefox or Chrome
- No Struts
- No IE

### Constraints

Other criterion to consider:

- Easily maintained by novice developers
- Easy to extend (add interactive widgets)
- Database model has already been designed and implemented

### Resources

Websites that demonstrate potential solutions:

- http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=723
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-richfaces/

### Question

What Java-based web framework would you recommend for this task?

Comment: Belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few possibilities:

- [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org)
- [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) (using JSF)

In my opinion, choosing a framework based on one component's needs is not the best option. But assuming you need a Java-based web framework, with Ajax support, I would recommend Play! It has a similar approach to Grails, but it is Java.

It is a real **web**-based stateless Java framework, with an enthusiastic and active community, and great [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/home). There are no widget as you can have in JSF but with jQuery on the client side, that solution would work like a charm.

Comment: So, JSF seems ok with that. Choose a good implementation like RichFaces. There's an [example here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/listShuttle.jsf) with ajax support

Comment: No, RichFaces can't be integrated with Play. That's another framework, with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)?

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: I believe that thing is called "shuffle" not "shuttle"